# Modifying a blog page to only display posts from same category when next/prev link is pressed

Tags: php, wordpress, function, storefront

I've seen a very similar post to this and lots of other examples such as the wordpress documentation for custom functions here: 
[Function reference for next/prev post link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)

However, my example sits within what appears to be a custom function within the Storefront (woothemes) theme and so I'm having trouble incorporating the "$in_same_term = true," in the right way without breaking the functionality. Here is the (raw) bit of code in the 'post.php' file within the theme where I think I need to somehow incorporate the "$in_same_term = true,"...

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_paging_nav' ) ) {
/**
 * Display navigation to next/previous set of posts when applicable.
 */
function storefront_paging_nav() {
    global $wp_query;
        $args = array(
        'type'      => 'list',
        'next_text' => _x( 'Next', 'Next post', 'storefront' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>',
        'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span>&nbsp' . _x( 'Previous', 'Previous post', 'storefront' ),
        );

    the_posts_pagination( $args );
}
    if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_post_nav' ) ) {
/**
 * Display navigation to next/previous post when applicable.
 */

function storefront_post_nav() {

    $args = array(
        'next_text' => '%title &nbsp;<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>',
        'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span>&nbsp;%title',
        );
    the_post_navigation( $args );
}
    }
```

I'm thinking I could be close as loads of searches have revealed the same kind of info, I'm just not integrating it properly...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how best to incorporate this functionality!

Comment: `the_posts_pagination()` does not have an `in_same_term` parameter...However, functions like [`nex_post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) do...

Comment: @rnevius thanks for that - are you saying that I should be able to write a separate function (alongside the existing 'the_posts_pagination' function)? Or do I add it to the function.php file and not this post.php file?

Answer (score 1):

You have just to add `'in_same_term' => true` in the array of the `storefont_post_nav` function

```
function storefront_post_nav() {
    $args = array(
        'next_text' => '%title &nbsp;<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>',
        'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span>&nbsp;%title',
        'in_same_term' => true,   
    );
}
```

Is possible to add other options in the array. You can have a look here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_navigation/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my main problem here was trying to incorporate the code in the wrong place - all I had to do was change the `next_post_link` parameter in this file: `wp-includes/link-template.php`. (Not the `post.php` file as I was trying to do).

It's worth noting for each next and previous link there were 2 sets of parameters where `$in_same_term = false` needed to be changed to `true`.

Works a treat now!

Comment: I highly recommend that you avoid editing core WordPress files (i.e. anything in *wp-includes/* or *wp-admin/*). Any changes you make there will be overwritten if you update WordPress in the future. Instead, take a look at how `the_post_pagination()` works, and craft your own version in your theme's template files.